# Java library to visualize database table relationships

Tags: java, sql, user-interface, relational-database, visualization

Does anyone know of a Java library that would assist in creating a GUI component to visualize the relationships between tables in an SQL database, similar to the Relationships pane in Access, or the Diagrams function in SQL Server Enterprise Manager.

The closest I have been able to discover is the Prefuse library, however I would need to extract the database structure and build the graph manually - is there a simpler way to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use [Visual Library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/).  I like Prefuse as well, but Visual Library's api is more Swing like if you are a Swing developer.  Another option is [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) which some people like.  You would still have to extract the database structure yourself though this is fairly straight forward using [jdbc](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/Jdbc-meta-data-get-tables.shtml).

Comment: Thanks Jay, this looks promising, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

[yFiles](http://www.yworks.com/yfiles) is a commercial graph and visualization library for Java / .NET / Ajax / Flex / Android that has been used for the exact same use in the [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com) (JDBC) SQL client (free & commercial version). [GraphML](http://graphml.graphdrawing.org) files exported from yFiles (and yFiles based windows in DBVisualizer) can be edited / (re)formatted in the (free) [yEd Graph editor](http://www.yworks.com/yed).

Extracting the database structure through the JDBC metadata programmatically might look straightforward, but from experience I can say that there's a fair bit of difference between JDBC drivers/database platforms. Also, depending on database platform, details needed and authorization levels used the results yielded might differ.

(N.B. I have no affiliation to either product other than being a user of the free editions of yEd and DBVisualizer, and include them in this answer because using the combination of these programs can give a good preview on the library features needed for such a project, and can be used as comparison check for its results).